# How to avoid showing characters like Ä in android keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-keypad

I am stuck in an issue where one of my user entering characters like Ä in an edittext and I am preparing an XML from that data. Due to encoding issue I can't prepare a valid XML from these kind of characters. Is there anyway I can stop user to enter such kind of characters or can I hide these characters from android default keyboard itself ?

Regards

Comment: Rather than forbidding these characters better fix your encoding issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can restrict the user to enter only specific characters in the edit text like below,

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/YourEdittextId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:privateImeOptions="nm"
    android:digits="0123456789 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" />
```

Above code restrict user to enter only English digits, letters and space

Answer (score 0):

Hide suggestion string in your edittext.

```
android:inputType="textFilter"
```

Answer (score -1):

Few days before I was facing same issue I solved this by creating below method.

```
public static String stripSpecialUTFChars(String string) {
    return string.replaceAll("\u0080", "");
  }
```

Please pass your String to above method and use this like below

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(stripSpecialUTFChars(yourString)));
```

actually this issue is due to UTF characters.